# Is there any event which is called whenever there is a change in the MYSQL database data?

Tags: mysql, events, refresh, chat

Is there any event which detects changes in the database tables? Im trying to do a chat box. It works fine. Except that it needs to be refreshed at regular seconds of interval to get the data. But, this would eat up lot of server load. SO, i was thinking of a event which triggers any changes in the database data. Suggest me the best solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use triggers

Comment: Use triggers? Can u refer any resources, that i can be helped of?

Comment: could you try googling mysql triggers

Comment: [this might help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: What programming language did you use to create the chat program? Perhaps using triggers and stored procedures is not the best thing. Rather using messages via sockets should be the way to go... I haven't tried this with MySQL but I think there's quite a lot of docs on the subject. Heres a start - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use triggers as presented in the comments. Problem with that: a trigger can only be triggered to execute an sql statemnt. So you could us a trigger, and create some kind of "activity" table with proper indexes. Problem: you still need to check this activity table! To  reduce load, you should write a server component to your chat program that notifeis all clients. This way, only the server has to check to database regularly and not each client.

Without more information what language you are writing in, we can not help you more I guess.